# Angular-cli and jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular-cli

I am trying to use some jQuery plugins in my angular2 app created with angular-cli.

As described in the doc, I installed the libraries I need using npm and, when available, the types too.
I then added styles and scripts in the `angular-cli.json`, and if I open the chrome debugger I can see that the libraries are correctly loaded.

The problem is that every time I try to use any jQuery plugin, I always get a js error in the console which says "the method is not a function".

I've created a small example using jQuery and fullcalendar, and it's forkable from this GitHub repo.

https://github.com/vmilitello/jquery-plugin

**Note**: *the problem exists only with JQuery plugins that needs a selector to run (like `$("#myItem").fullcalendar()` or `$(".foo").steps()`). 
If you use libraries like Sweetalert, the problem doesn't appear.*

I am sure I am missing something, but I really cannot figured it out what it is!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ( if you didn't )

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

You need to write manual typing's for your plugin.

Create structure:

```
/custom_typings
 /fullcalendar
  /index.d.ts
```

Than in index.d.ts something like:

```
interface JQuery {
  fullCalendar(options?: any): JQuery;
}
```

Than in tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types",
  "../custom_typings"
]
```

Comment: My problem is not with types. What you suggest just let me avoid to cast the jQuery selector while I am writing my typescript file. Basically instead of (<any>$("#calendar")).fullcalendar();, I can write $("#calendar").fullcalendar();. But this is barely related to my question. I updated the branch on GitHub to demonstrate that this solution doesn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: name your typing file index.d.ts not index.ts, and jQuery function is not fullcalendar, it is fullCalendar, i tried it on your repo and it works

Comment: Thank you! I was actually playing around with some guys on gitter.im, and we found the problem as well. Thank you for updating the branch! Appreciate it. I will leave the branch there hoping that it could help someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All correct besides one small detail without which it is not working.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601352/using-jquery-and-other-plugins-with-angular-cli-rc0-in-angular2) in the last part, you must have in your component

```
declare var $:any
```

Then $ will be global and will see the `fullCalendar()` function, otherwise it did not work for me.