# Using jquery and other plugins with angular-cli rc0 in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular-cli

I've a angular project created using @angular/cli-1.0.0-rc0.
I need to use:
 - jquery
 - a query widget (in my example http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Using 'webpack-bundle-analyzer' I can see that jquery is imported in vendor.bundle.js (if imported in a ts file) but not globally exposed, so jquery plugin fails to load itself.

Is there a way to:

- load jquery (and others libraries such as momentjs) only in scripts bundle?
- do not add jquery in vendor bundle but add it only as reference?

---

If I put jquery between scripts:[] section in .angular-cli.json

- jquery library is added both in vendor and scripts bundles.
- $ instance in typescript file is not the one exposed globally, so the plugin is available in window.$ but it is not available in angular directive.

---

In previous versions of angular-cli, a solution found on stackoverflow was to:

- create a vendor.ts with:

  - import * as jquery from 'jquery';
  - window['jQuery'] = window['$'] = jquery;
- add vendor.ts in scripts: [] structure

but this solution apparently doesn't work anymore. I receive a webpack error during compilation.

---

At the moment, as a workaround:

- jquery, moment, eonasdan datetime picker... added in scripts[]
- jquery.. not imported in typescript files (just declared as "declare var $:any".
  I don't like it, but I cannot find any other solutions.
  Also this one ([How to include jQuery properly in angular cli 1.0.0-rc.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510334/how-to-include-jquery-properly-in-angular-cli-1-0-0-rc-0)) doesn't work for me.

Comment: Refer this answer [**Plain Javascript as Angular2 Service**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service/42235817#42235817)

Comment: The question is: "I can import jquery in angular-cli, how can I add plain jquery plugin to the jquery instance added in angular injector"?
The link you added is about a third party javascript that doesn't have dependencies. A jquery plugin has dependency to jquery plugin.